# No puedo acceder a una variable dentro de una promesa en JS

Tags: javascript, axios, strapi

No puedo acceder a entry desde fuera del cuerpo `.then()`

```
module.exports = createCoreController('api::soap.soap', {
   async soapReq(ctx) {
            let xmls = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
            <soap:Body>\
            <InvertStringCase xmlns="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">\
            <sAString>ESTO ESTA EN MAYUSCULAS</sAString>\
            </InvertStringCase>\
            </soap:Body>\
            </soap:Envelope>';
            console.log("Llega al controler");

            axios.post('https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/TextCasing.wso',
            xmls,
            {
                headers:
                    { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' }
            }).then( res => {
                const entry = strapi.entityService.create('api::soap.soap', {
                    data: {
                        respXML: res.data,
                    },
                  });
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            // .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
           
            ctx.body = entry;

    }
});
```

¿Cual es la manera correcta de acceder a los datos de adentro?
Necesito que los datos se almacenen en 'ctx.body' para poder retornarlo al cliente.

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es volver a ejecutar un método then luego de retornar la respuesta del servidor.

Comment: Para que tenes una funcion asincrona si en ninguna parte esperas resultados?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes solucionarlo usando `await` así:

```
const entry = await axios.post('https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/TextCasing.wso',
        xmls,
        {
            headers:
                { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' }
        }).then( res => {
            const entry = strapi.entityService.create('api::soap.soap', {
                data: {
                    respXML: res.data,
                },
              });
            console.log(res.data);
            return entry;
        })
        // .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
       
ctx.body = entry;
```